# Insertar filas en una columna especificada por cada fila creada anteriormente

Tags: c#

Buen día, mi problema es que estoy trabajando en un proyecto, en el que estoy usando `DataGrids` y me encuentro con un problema:
El usuario ingresa información en `textbox` le dan a **"agregar"** y genera una fila con la información de los `textboxs`, ahora lo que quiero hacer es que por cada fila creada me rellene en la columna vacía con los datos de un `textbox` fijo **(Es otro boton no el de agregar)** como podría hacerlo?

[image: campo requerido]

Este es el código del boton "Agregar":

```
{
     if (descuento.Text == string.Empty)
     {
         descuento.Text = "0";
     }
     dataGridView1.Rows.Add(prodcod.Text, articulo.Text, unidad.Text, preciou.Text, cantidad.Text, subtotal.Text, descuento.Text, total.Text);
     prodcod.Clear();
     articulo.Clear();
     unidad.Clear();
     preciou.Clear();
     cantidad.Clear();
     subtotal.Clear();
     descuento.Clear();
     total.Clear();
     prodcod.Focus();                      
}
```

Comment: A ver si entendí, cuando ya tienes los datos agregados, presionas el otro botón y y debe colocar en el campo `ID` el valor de un `TextBox` que será igual para todas las filas? por ejemplo `Id = 5` en todas las filas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si entendí lo que quieres es agregar un valor fijo a cada fila agregada tomando el valor que contiene un `TextBox`:

En el evento `Click` de tu otro botón coloca algo como esto:

```
private void otro_boton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int indice = 0; indice < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; indice++)
        {
             dataGridView1.Rows[indice].Cells[8].Value = tuTextBoxFijo.Text;
        }
     }
     else
        MessageBox.Show("No hay filas agregadas.");
}
```

> `Cells[8]` representa la columna `ID` tomada por su posición actual en la imagen.

Comment: Perfecto amigo eso era lo que necesitaba! Muchísimas gracias!!!

Comment: @p0ncho14 Que bueno, no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada, por si otros usuarios tienen el mismo problema, Saludos!